# How to find close matches within a single column with Rails and Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, duplicates

I'm aware of ways to find exact duplicate records within a single table with basic SQL and active record query language. But I need to know how to implement a close match search is performed, I'd like to take into account spelling errors. What is the best way to find potential duplicates and close matches in a rails app? I'm using MySQL as the database.

Edit: the type of data I would want to match are strings, they are stored in the database as strings.

Comment: what is a close match? string based?

Comment: Yes string based. I'm not sure of the available methods or where to start.

Answer (score 5):

I think [thinking_sphinx](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx) and [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com) might be two interesting tools for you. What you want is provided by a set of feature called full text search wich is a big topic to explain in a single answer but you will probably want to learn about "word proximity" and "lexemes"